# Opening a Save As dialog box and exit on Cancel

Tags: excel, vba

i am creating an automated Request to Purchase, where the user can raise a purchase request and when he click a button, a save as dialogue box will popup and allow the user to save the file in a desired location, then increment the RTP number and close the excel sheet.
below is my code:

```
Sub sbUnProtectSheet()
Worksheets("RTP").Unprotect "123"
End Sub
Sub sbProtectSheet()
Worksheets("RTP").Protect "123", True, True
End Sub

Sub PostToRegister()
Dim WS1 As Worksheet
Dim WS2 As Worksheet
Set WS1 = Worksheets("RTP")
Set WS2 = Worksheets("Register")
nextrow = WS2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
WS2.Cells(nextrow, 1).Resize(1, 7).Value = Array(WS1.Range("P8"), WS1.Range("P7"), WS1.Range("P10"), WS1.Range("P11"), WS1.Range("L9"), WS1.Range("TOT"), WS1.Range("P9"))
End Sub
Sub nextRTP()
Call sbUnProtectSheet
Sheets("RTP").Range("P7").Value = Sheets("RTP").Range("P7").Value + 1
Range("B15:O26").ClearContents
Sheets("RTP").Range("E8:I8").ClearContents
Sheets("RTP").Range("P9:P10").ClearContents
Sheets("RTP").Range("L7:L9").ClearContents
Sheets("RTP").Range("C32:I35").ClearContents
Sheets("RTP").Range("B38:P40").ClearContents
Sheets("RTP").CheckBoxes.Value = False
Call sbProtectSheet
End Sub

Sub SaveRTPWithNewName()
 Dim USERRESPONSE As Boolean
    USERRESPONSE = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show(PDFfileName, 52)
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("RTP").Cells(8, "E"), Sheets("RTP").Cells(7, "L"), Sheets("RTP").Cells(8, "L"), Sheets("RTP").Cells(9, "L"), Sheets("RTP").Cells(9, "P"), Sheets("RTP").Cells(10, "P"), Sheets("RTP").Cells(38, "B")) = "7" Then

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("RTP").Cells(15, "B"), Sheets("RTP").Cells(15, "C"), Sheets("RTP").Cells(15, "E"), Sheets("RTP").Cells(15, "M"), Sheets("RTP").Cells(15, "N"), Sheets("RTP").Cells(15, "O")) = "6" Then

Call sbUnProtectSheet
'PostToRegister
Call Save_Workbook_As_PDF
If USERRESPONSE = False Then
MsgBox ("you clicked no!")
Exit Sub
End If

nextRTP
Call sbProtectSheet
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Else: MsgBox "NO ITEM INPUT RECEIVED. ENTER ALEAST ONE ITEM TO RAISE RTP"
End If
Else: MsgBox "ENTER ALL DETAILS TO RAISE RTP"
End If
End Sub

Public Sub Save_Workbook_As_PDF()

    Dim i As Integer, PDFindex As Integer
    Dim PDFfileName As String
   
       
    With ActiveWorkbook
        PDFfileName = "RTP " & Range("P7").Value & ".pdf"
    End With
    
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
  
   
    PDFindex = 0
      For i = 1 To .Filters.Count
        If InStr(VBA.UCase(.Filters(i).Description), "PDF") > 0 Then PDFindex = i
       Next

        .Title = "Save workbook as "
        .InitialFileName = PDFfileName
        .FilterIndex = PDFindex
                If .Show Then
         
           Worksheets("RTP").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PDFfileName, _
                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
               
                End If
        
                       
    End With
    
End Sub
```

the problem is, even if the user click cancel, the code continue to run and increment the rtp # by 2, i want the code to exit when the user click cancel...any clue??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your simplified code and this should be working answer. But your code might have other errors (you are working with activeworkbook etc.). But try this simple example it should show you how it works when you select something or not.

```
Sub SaveRTPWithNewName_simple()
 

If Save_Workbook_As_PDF = False Then
    MsgBox "you clicked no!"
    Exit Sub
Else
    MsgBox "You selected something"
End If

MsgBox "Next procedure nextRTP"
MsgBox "Next procedure sbProtectSheet"

End Sub

Public Function Save_Workbook_As_PDF() As Boolean

Dim PDFindex As Integer
Dim PDFfileName As String

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

    PDFindex = 0
    PDFfileName = "dummy name"
    
    .Title = "Save workbook as "
    .InitialFileName = PDFfileName
    .FilterIndex = PDFindex
            
    If .Show <> 0 Then
        Save_Workbook_As_PDF = True
        'export file
    Else
        Save_Workbook_As_PDF = False
    End If
    
                   
End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This could help you... Focus on part where you have If .Show

```
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
    If .Show <> 0 Then
        'continue
    Else
        'enable events and screen updating
        Exit Sub
        'or you can use End instead of Exit Sub (depends on how you are nesting your procedures)
    End If
End With
```

Edit:

After posting my answer I noticed that you ask for some kind of user response in your "SaveRTPWithNewName". So i converted your Save_Workbook_As_PDF to Function instead of Sub and that function returns boolean = true or false. See 2 modified procedures.

```
Sub SaveRTPWithNewName()
 Dim USERRESPONSE As Boolean
    USERRESPONSE = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show(PDFfileName, 52)
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("RTP").Cells(8, "E"),     Sheets("RTP").Cells(7, "L"), Sheets("RTP").Cells(8, "L"), Sheets("RTP").Cells(9, "L"), Sheets("RTP").Cells(9, "P"), Sheets("RTP").Cells(10, "P"),     Sheets("RTP").Cells(38, "B")) = "7" Then

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("RTP").Cells(15, "B"), Sheets("RTP").Cells(15, "C"), Sheets("RTP").Cells(15, "E"), Sheets("RTP").Cells(15, "M"), Sheets("RTP").Cells(15, "N"), Sheets("RTP").Cells(15, "O")) = "6" Then

Call sbUnProtectSheet
'PostToRegister

If Save_Workbook_As_PDF = False Then
MsgBox ("you clicked no!")
Exit Sub
End If

nextRTP
Call sbProtectSheet
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Else: MsgBox "NO ITEM INPUT RECEIVED. ENTER ALEAST ONE ITEM TO RAISE RTP"
End If
Else: MsgBox "ENTER ALL DETAILS TO RAISE RTP"
End If
End Sub

Public Function Save_Workbook_As_PDF() As Boolean

Dim i As Integer, PDFindex As Integer
Dim PDFfileName As String

   
With ActiveWorkbook
    PDFfileName = "RTP " & Range("P7").Value & ".pdf"
End With

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)


PDFindex = 0
  For i = 1 To .Filters.Count
    If InStr(VBA.UCase(.Filters(i).Description), "PDF") > 0 Then PDFindex = i
   Next

    .Title = "Save workbook as "
    .InitialFileName = PDFfileName
    .FilterIndex = PDFindex
            
            If .Show <> 0 Then
                Save_Workbook_As_PDF = True
     
       Worksheets("RTP").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PDFfileName, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
            Else
                Save_Workbook_As_PDF = False
            End If
    
                   
End With

End Function
```

Fucntions are good to use instead of Subs when you need to retrieve 1 result from procedure. When you need more Results then you should use parameters defined in procedure header with ByRef...

Hope this helps

Comment: hi, thanks for your resp?onse, but it did not work quiet well. is possible that i can send you the excel file to check it.? maybe you  can share with me your email address.

Comment: Guess there is no need for that.. .Maybe try to change If .Show Then for If .Show <> 0 Then I also edited my original answer to include this condition.

Comment: Sorry I got confused now..so where is the answer you suggest?

Comment: This answer we are commenting i changed code there. So try again please and let me know if it works.Sorry for confusion

Comment: Hi Mate, No its not working  I would suggest to send you the file over to get what i mean and trial run it your self